# How to call javascript file in laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to call JavaScript file, but I got error that function is not found

I want to call JavaScript file on this page.

This is my **blade**:

I put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/lihatjadwal.js')}}"></script>
```

[image]

This is my **JavaScript** file (lihatjadwal.js):
[image]

This is my **route**:
[image]

This is my **controller**:
[image]

I got error like this:
[image]
[image]

Thank you if somebody want to help me :)

Comment: Please copy your code into the question. Images aren't effective for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call laravel function to an external javascript file,

In you case you could use your url like,

```
url: '/daftarPeriksa/lihatjadwal',
type: "POST"
```

And try to use stackoverflow code editor instead of share image.

Comment: this is the first time using laravel, thank you very much :D